# Call namespace Function from Strings

Tags: javascript

Now I use this method to call functions inside a Namespaces:

```
eval('Admin.' + section + '.' + action + '()');
```

But I don't like use `eval`, I need to call methods in different namespaces creating the call using string given me from JSON, but I think this is not good system, because `eval` it's dangerous.

Any other form to make this works? Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I dynamically call a JavaScript object's method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5112793/how-do-i-dynamically-call-a-javascript-objects-method)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `[]` operator to do that:

```
Admin[ section ][ action ]();
```

Comment: is called "square bracket notation", see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Objects_and_properties