# How to call to dyanimc function in javascript

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I dynamically call a JavaScript object’s method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5112793/how-do-i-dynamically-call-a-javascript-objects-method)

I have function for different properties

```
setCar : function() {}
setBike : function() {}
setAirPlane : function (){}
```

I have object in format key value

```
var json = { Car : "Car1",
             Bike : "Bike1",
             AirPlane  : "test1" }
```

I want to call to the set function in dynamic way according to the object values:

```
 updateProperties : function(json) {        
 for ( var property in json) {
     //set + property (AdditionalProperties[property])
 };
```

in the property I have the name of the function(Car,Bike,AirPlane) and in AdditionalProperties[property] I have the value of the property ( Car1,Bike1,test1.

Is it possible to do it ?

Comment: ***This is not a JSON, this is a JavaScript object!***

Comment: I fixed it sorry I meant JavaScript object!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not? It is possible to do:

```
for (var property in obj) {
    typeof funcContainer["set" + property] === "function"
      && funcContainer["set" + property](obj[property]);
}
```

Where `funcContainer` is:

```
var funcContainer = {
    setCar : function() {},
    setBike : function() {},
    setAirPlane : function() {}
};
```

Comment: what is funcContainer  ?

Comment: Can I wrote : updateProperties : function(json) {        
 for ( var property in json) {
     this.["set"+ property](AdditionalProperties[property])
 };

Comment: @user1365697 What does `this` refer to?

Comment: the object the hold the functions ( setCar,....)

Comment: @user1365697 Then there is no need in `.` dot after `this`.

Answer (score 1):

If

```
objWithFuncts = {
...
setCar : function() {}
setBike : function() {}
setAirPlane : function (){}
...
}
```

Than you can do:

```
 updateProperties : function(json) {        
 for ( var property in json) {
       if(json.hasOwnProperty(property) && objWithFuncs["set" + property])
           objWithFuncs["set" + property](AdditionalProperties[property])
 };
```

Just remember that you can access any property of an object using index, like: `obj["propName"]`  which is equal to `obj.propName`

Comment: There is no need in `hasOwnProperty` here.

Comment: Can I wrote : updateProperties : function(json) {        
 for ( var property in json) {
     this.["set"+ property](AdditionalProperties[property])
 };

Comment: if you call it like `objWithFuncs.updateProperties(json); ` than yes, but you have a mistake:  `this.["set"+ property]` should be simply  `this["set"+ property]` (no dot after this)

Comment: @VisioN yes, with example `json` object - it is not required, but as for me, it is better to put it there - who knows how that object is created exactly?